# solving a first order differential equation with a variable-dependent function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm gonna solve equation below:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = -a(x-x_{p})$

where $x_p$ is, itself, a function of $t$.

I know the answer is as following (initial condition is evaluated in $t=t^{'}$):

$x(t) = x(t^{'})e^{-a(t-t^{'})}+ae^{-at}\int_{t^{'}}^{t} e^{ak} dk)$

But I have no idea about the process for derivation of answer above.

Comment: @Moo: Exactly... Sorry for the wrong term... I'd fixed that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{dx}{dt} = -a(x-x_{p})\quad$ is a first order inhomogeneous linear ODE.

The solution of the related homogeneous ODE  $\quad\frac{dx}{dt} = -ax\quad$ is : $\quad x=c\;e^{-at}$

The usual method of variation of parameter consists in replacing the parameter $c$ by an unknown function :

$x(t)=f(t)e^{-at}\quad\to\quad \frac{dx}{dt} =\frac{df}{dt}e^{-at} -af(t)e^{-at} = -a(x-x_p)= -f(t)e^{-at}+ax_p$

$\frac{df}{dt}=ax_p(t)e^{at} \quad\to\quad f(t)=\int ax_p(t)e^{at}dt+c$

The constant $c$ is evaluated from the initial condition : $x(t')=f(t')e^{-at'}\quad\to\quad f(t')=e^{at'}x(t')$

$$f(t)=\int_{t'}^t ax_p(\theta)e^{a\theta}d\theta+e^{at'}x(t')$$

$x(t)=f(t)e^{-at}=e^{-at}\left(\int_{t'}^t ax_p(\theta)e^{a\theta}d\theta+e^{at'}x(t')\right)$

$$x(t)=e^{-a(t-t')}x(t')+a\;e^{-at}\int_{t'}^t x_p(\theta)e^{a\theta}d\theta$$

Comment: Your kindness...